# Selenium web driver sendkeys() not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am using sendkeys() to fill the form in my application. When I try to submit the form with all the values in the fields are correct and as per the requirement the form fails to submit. But when i key press the input, the field accepts the values. Can someone please help to overcome this issue? Below is the snippet of the code I use:

```
WebElement fname = driver.findElement(By.id("txtFirstName"));
fname.clear();
fname.sendKeys("Test");
```

Below is the html,

```
<input name="ctl19$ctl20$ctl00$txtFirstName" type="text" maxlength="50"
 id="ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtFirstName" tabindex="182" class="DTC_txtStandard"
 onchange="DealerTrackCanada.CommonObjects.Util.ExtenderContr‌​ols.DataChangeEventM‌​anager.onApplicantNa‌​meChange('ctl19_ctl2‌​0_ctl00_txtFirstName‌​', 'ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtMiddleName', 'ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtLastName');" 
 oldbgc="rgb(255, 255, 153)" style="background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255);">
```

Comment: The field accepts the values or not? Is it throwing any exception? Share the HTML of the element as well please.

Comment: In some browsers, you need to "focus" on the element first and then you can send keys

Comment: Hi, No Its not throwing any exceptions. Below is the html,



<input name="ctl19$ctl20$ctl00$txtFirstName" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtFirstName" tabindex="182" class="DTC_txtStandard" onchange="DealerTrackCanada.CommonObjects.Util.ExtenderControls.DataChangeEventManager.onApplicantNameChange('ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtFirstName', 'ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtMiddleName', 'ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtLastName');" oldbgc="rgb(255, 255, 153)" style="background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255);">

Comment: Your code is interacting with element `By.id("txtFirstName")` but you have shown us HTML of element `id="ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtFirstName"`. There are two completely different elements.

Comment: As krokodilko said earilier in the comments. You're using the wrong id element. You have to do this to reach the element you want WebElement fname = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl19_ctl20_ctl00_txtFirstName"));

Comment: I actually use the same element Id as it is in HTML. when I added it I shortened it. If that is the case I should be getting element not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptExecutor

```
   WebElement fname =      driver.findElement(By.id("txtFirstName"));                                

     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fname);
```